# PHP/MYSQL - Functions mysqli_data_seek() and mysqli_fetch_assoc() produce errors on live site but not on local development?

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I am having trouble with one of my scripts. What basically happens is that my use of `mysqli_data_seek()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` produces the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_data_seek() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /usr/home/myacc/includes/html/shop/categoryMain.html.php on line 49
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /usr/home/myacc/includes/html/shop/categoryMain.html.php on line 50
```

This is the code relating to those two lines:

```
mysqli_data_seek($subsSql, 0);
while($rowSubs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subsSql))
```

These errors only occur when the script runs on my hosted (live) website. In my local development (latest version of WAMP) this script runs without error and produces the desired effect...

Here is the script in its full context:

```
//categories to local array
$catsQuery = "
    SELECT id, category, catDirPath
    FROM categories
    ORDER BY category
";
$catsSql = mysqli_query($link, $catsQuery);
$cats = array();
mysqli_data_seek($catsSql, 0);
while($rowCats = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catsSql))
{
    $cats[$rowCats['id']]['catName'] = $rowCats['category'];
    $cats[$rowCats['id']]['catPath'] = $rowCats['catDirPath'];
}

// subCats to local array
$subsQuery = "
    SELECT id, subCat, category_id, subDirPath
    FROM subCats, sub_categories
    WHERE subCats.id = sub_categories.sub_id
    ORDER BY subCat
";
$subsSql = mysqli_query($link, $subsQuery);
$subs = array();
mysqli_data_seek($subsSql, 0);
while($rowSubs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subsSql))
{
    $subs[$rowSubs['id']]['subName'] = $rowSubs['subCat'];
    $subs[$rowSubs['id']]['catId'] = $rowSubs['category_id'];
    $subs[$rowSubs['id']]['subPath'] = $rowSubs['subDirPath'];
}

// loop through categories and if subs exist, add to resultset and display
foreach ($cats as $catId => $cat)
{
    ...
            foreach ($subs as $subId => $sub)
            {
                ...
            }
    ...
}
```

Could someone by chance spot a problem with the way I have coded this script or possibly suggest a reason as to why this would work via wamp and not the apache server used with my web host?

Any suggestions or advice relating to this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time in reading through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) for mysqli_query says

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

That means that your query failed. Ensure that **$link** is connected ok, and double check the syntax of the **$subsQuery** and **$catsSql**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and insight provided! As stated this does work in my local development. And on my host the database is a duplicate of the local version, so i do not see a reason behind the failure. Also, notice that the error is produced relating to the second query, meaning that the first query was successful which basically means that `$link` is connected. And as for the syntax, as I said, its the exact same as the local version which does work fine... Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: what does "the database is a duplicate" mean? does it mean that the data is exactly the same, that the mysql daemon is of the exact same version, or both? ;) have you tried running the query directly on the mysql daemon?

Comment: @davogotland I meant that it was exported to .sql via phpmyadmin in wamp, then imported via phpmyadmin on my hosted account (the versions of mysql are not the same, but the data is). Please see my answer for clarification to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the referral to the table: `subCats` is incorrect. the actual name of this table is `subcats`. In the local version, it seems that it is not case sensitive whereas in the hosted version it is case sensitive.

If someone could explain to me the reason behind this, the answer will go for that!

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned one copy is WAMP.. the hosted is likely LAMP.. im not certain about MYSQL specifically, but it is often the case that windows is not case sensitive and linux is (eg. command line, filenames).. see this thread http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,58873,58874,quote=1#REPLY

Comment: @MikeGraf yup, +1 for that comment. i hope readers of this question sees it! it's somewhat dangerous to develop php/mysql code on a windows machine which will later run on a *nix system. windows is just not strict enough.